# Teradata SQL: Calculate running totals if a condition is met

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a dataset that contains the following columns and data:

```
Customer | Week_number | Amount
cust1    |  0          | 100
cust1    |  1          | 200
cust1    |  3          | 300
cust2    |  0          | 1000
cust2    |  1          | 2000
```

I need to calculate fortnightly totals for each customer.

With the window functions, I am able to do this:

```
SELECT 
 CUSTOMER, WEEK_NUMBER
, SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY WEEK_NUMBER ROWS 1 PRECEDING) AS FORTNIGHT_AMOUNT
FROM AMOUNT
```

But this adds up the amount even if there is no amount for the previous week. In the example above, for cust1, 3rd row, it adds up week 3 and week 1. The amount should only be added if the week_number is 1 less than the current row's week. Is this possible? Thanks for the help.

What I am getting:

```
Customer | Week_number | Fortnight_Amount
cust1    |  0          | 100
cust1    |  1          | 300
cust1    |  3          | **500**
cust2    |  0          | 1000
cust2    |  1          | 3000
```

Expected Result:

```
Customer | Week_number | Fortnight_Amount
cust1    |  0          | 100
cust1    |  1          | 300
cust1    |  3          | **300**
cust2    |  0          | 1000
cust2    |  1          | 3000
```

Comment: Please show us your expected results.

Comment: What if there is a record for `cust1` with `week_number``4`? Would you reset the `sum`, or keep adding it to the running `sum`?

Comment: If there was one with week 4 (say amount=400), then the fortnight_amount for week 4 would be 700 (week 4 + week 3)

Comment: For non-English speakers, a fortnight is two weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only two weeks/rows your query can be further simplified to a single STATS-step in Explain (as both OLAP-functions apply the same PARTITION/ORDER) :

```
SELECT T.*
, CASE 
    WHEN MAX(WEEK_NUMBER) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY WEEK_NUMBER ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) + 1 = WEEK_NUMBER
    THEN SUM(AMOUNT)      OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY WEEK_NUMBER ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
   ELSE AMOUNT
  END AS TWO_WEEK_SUM_AMOUNT
FROM MY_TABLE T
ORDER BY CUSTOMER, WEEK_NUMBER
```

Of course this assumes that weeks start with 0 and there's no previous year week 52/53.

Comment: is there a way this can be used for calculating running totals over 4 weeks.. the conditions are the same.. a week might or might not have a total and the total should be added up only if the week number is between the current week and 3 less than the current.. Thanks..

Comment: You could add a check for the three previous rows and add this individual row (looks ugly, but should be efficient): `CASE 
    WHEN MAX(WEEK_NUMBER) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY WEEK_NUMBER ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) BETWEEN WEEK_NUMBER - 3 AND WEEK_NUMBER 
    THEN SUM(AMOUNT)      OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY WEEK_NUMBER ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
   ELSE 0 END + ...` Repeat the CASE for rows 2 and 3 preceding. If you're on TD16.10+ you can simolify it using LAG.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to ignore week numbers that are not immediatly sequential, you could use `lag()` first, and then do a window `sum()`:

```
select
    customer,
    week_number,
    sum(
        case when lag_week_number is null or week_number = lag_week_number + 1 
            then amount
            else 0 
        end
    ) over(partition by customer order by week_number) fortnight_amount
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        lag(week_number) over(partition by customer order by week_number) lag_week_number
    from mytable t
) t
```

Actually you might actually want to *reset* the `sum` when a there is a gap in week_numbers. For this, which is some kind of gaps-and-islands assignment, you would proceed differently: the idea is to do a cumulative `sum` to start a new group when two consecutive week numbers ae note sequential, and then sum within each group:

```
select 
    customer,
    week_number,
    sum(amount) over(partition by customer, grp order by week_date) fortnight_amount
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(
            case 
                when lag_week_number is null or week_number = lag_week_number + 1 
                then 0
                else 1
            end
        ) grp
    from (
        select 
            t.*, 
            lag(week_number) over(partition by customer order by week_number) lag_week_number
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been trying to run the first answer that you provided and it fails with the error 'Data Type "WEEK_NUMBER" does not match a Defined Type name'. WEEK_NUMBER is an integer..

Answer (score 0):

You want `range` partitioning, not `row` partitioning:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, WEEK_NUMBER,
       SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER
                         ORDER BY WEEK_NUMBER 
                         RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                        ) AS FORTNIGHT_AMOUNT
FROM AMOUNT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Gordon and @GMB for both your answers. Unfortunately, I am not able to use both the LAG function or the RANGE partitioning in Teradata SQL. But I was able to use the concepts that you both described to get to the below answer.

```
SELECT 
CUSTOMER
, WEEK_NUMBER
, LAG_WEEK_NUMBER
, AMOUNT
, CASE 
  WHEN WEEK_NUMBER = LAG_WEEK_NUMBER + 1 
  THEN SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY WEEK_NUMBER ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
  ELSE AMOUNT
END AS TWO_WEEK_SUM_AMOUNT
FROM (
  SELECT 
  T.*
  , MAX(WEEK_NUMBER) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY WEEK_NUMBER ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS LAG_WEEK_NUMBER
  FROM MY_TABLE T
  ) T
ORDER BY CUSTOMER, WEEK_NUMBER
```

I was able to get the LAG function implementation in Teradata from @dnoeth's answer in these links:

```
MAX(WEEK_NUMBER) OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY WEEK_NUMBER ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS LAG_WEEK_NUMBER
```

[rows between 1 preceding and preceding 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48784722/rows-between-1-preceding-and-preceding-1)

[Teradata partitioned query ... following rows dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167738/teradata-partitioned-query-following-rows-dynamically)

Please let me know if you find any issues with the answer or if it can be improved in any way.